# WPF Datagrid get all checked rows (without using WPF binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I get all of the checked rows in WPF datagrid using C# code behind?

I'm trying a batch deletion with these codes but I need to get all checked rows first.

Here is my datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    GridLinesVisibility="All" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    CanUserAddRows="False"                      
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
            >

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseIdColumn" Binding="{Binding DiseaseId}" Header="DiseaseId" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseNameColumn" Binding="{Binding DiseaseName}" Header="Disease" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SymptomIdColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomId}" Header="SymptomId" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SymptomNameColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomName}" Header="Symptom" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding SymptomDescription}" Header="Description" Width="425" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="StatusIdColumn" Header="Delete"  IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Here is my attempted code behind

```
public List<DiseaseSymptomParams> GetSelectedDiseaseSymptom()
{

    var entiParams = new DiseaseSymptomParams();
    var selectedDiseases = new List<DiseaseSymptomParams>();

    try
    {
        // this will only get the highlighted row, not ALL the checked rows
        foreach (DiseaseSymptom itemSelected in DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid.SelectedItems) 
        {
            entiParams.Id = DefaultValue.GetInt(itemSelected.Id);                   

            selectedDiseases.Add(entiParams);

        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return selectedDiseases;

}
```

Comment: Use the items source property instead if selected items.

Comment: I still couldn't get the items that were checked.

Comment: If you're binding to a viewmodel datasource you should look to build this functionality in there too. I'd expect you will run into issues if you mix mvvm and code behind approaches. Certainly maintainability will be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

```
foreach (DiseaseSymptom item in DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid.ItemsSource)
{
    if (((CheckBox)StatusIdColumn.GetCellContent(item)).IsChecked == true)
    {
        selectedDiseases.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Not MVVM-compliant but pragmatic.